# Best practices when communicating with AS400 (IBM i) from .NET

Tags: .net, ibm-midrange

I need some help on what's important and best practices when building a .NET based reporting solution on top of an existing AS400 based system.

- What's the most suited integration
  technology (ODBC, OLE DB, ADO.NET)
  and does that depend on what version
  of AS400 we're talking about? Is it
  always DB2 databases or does that
  vary to? What other persistency system are usually used?
- Is it possible to call
  programs in the mainframe that has
  logic in them or is preferable to replicate that logic in the .NET layer
  and then call the mainframe DB directly?
- I guess a reporting system should be online and call the mainframe DB directly or are there other ways (for example file export etc.) that would be preferred?
- What technical details are important to find out before starting the project (AS400 version etc.) to eliminate problems.

Basically I'm interested (and will vote up) in all information and experiences from .NET/AS400 projects. I've never done it before and need to know the pitfalls before project start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not familiar with OS/400, be prepared for a *steep* learning curve. Try and reduce the pain by enlisting the local AS/400 wizard, it will be indispensable for writing the odd CL program, getting authorisations etc.

Personally I always stayed with the ODBC drivers supplied with Client Access, but only for read-only. I can't justify this, but a decade of AS/400 programming taught me that trying to update an AS/400 database from outside the AS/400 is a bad idea.

It is indeed possible to call AS/400 CL programs from your .NET app and, if the business logic is already programmed there, then using it makes sense; re-inventing it in .NET is expensive, error-prone and will be much slower.

Same message for reporting: use the existing ones if possible.

Things to look out for (some of these may well be outdated):

DB2 SQL has many subtle differences to other SQL dialects. Many DBMSs will accept

```
SELECT X, Y FROM A, B WHERE A.T=B.T
```

as equivalent to

```
SELECT X,Y FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.T=B.T
```

DB2 may or may not see it, depending on the tables. When it doesn't, the former can be very slow. That said, if you have a performance issue, there are some very slick tools to analyse the DB/2 query plans; you'll need your AS/400 wizard to use them though as they're a little obscure.

If you're in an international environment, handling code-pages needs care. Make *sure all* your AS/400s have the same system codepage.

If you're in a multi-AS/400 setup, be aware that local and remote tables can be accessed transparently (with passthrough).

OS/400 has a long history of extensive backward support. You will generally not have to worry about versions at all, as long as all the AS/400s you are talking to are on the same major release. It is also a very stable platform; operating system bugs are very rare and quickly fixed.

If you can manage it, get access to a test system with `*ALLOBJ` privilege. This will allow you to focus on the problem at hand and deal with the security issues later.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

Ok I used to work with and connect to AS/400 and mainframe systems from .NET several years ago. I might not be able to answer your questions directly but I can let you know what worked for me and some of the stuff I did in the past.

A common term for this type of work is [Enterprise Application Integration](http://www.google.com/search?q=enterprise+application+integration&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=/) (EAI) so you could start by reading up on that. As far as I know it is possible to have more than just DB2 databases on AS/400s. There were 2 ways in which we worked with green screen (or legacy) applications:

1. Access the data source/stores directly
2. Create a session, send keystrokes such as F10, F4 etc. that the legacy app uses to navigate through different screen, and grab data from fixed points on the legacy screen (this is sometimes called screen scraping).

To partially answer your first question, to access the data sources directly we created DSNs (data source name) using ODBC drivers which were available from 2 companies at the time, Rumba (made by Wall Data), and Attachmate (made by I think IBM). To create an ODBC DSN you typically went into Admin Tools/Data Sources and added a system DSN. You would need the (legacy system) host name, user name to log on with and password. We then used these DSNs inside .NET apps to create a connection to the legacy apps. If you have a DSN you can then use something like SQL Server DTS/SSIS to grab data from the source and save it in some location, whether that be the database, CSV files, Excel files etc. It's also more than likely possible to have a reporting tool (Crystal/SQL Server Reporting Services) access the data source directly using the DSN so you could report directly from the data source. Also you could probably create DSN-less connections as well, years ago we needed DSNs.

To partially answer your 2nd question it is possible to call and use the logic on green screen apps if you want to. A green screen is typically divided into a set number of rows and columns, and we used a standard called HLLAPI that sent keystrokes from a Windows system to positions on a legacy screen. We used Rumba for this which was available as an OCX control and I'm sure Attachmate is also. For example you could create a Winforms form with User ID and password text boxes, then create a session to the legacy app, and usually the first screen would be a logon screen. Then using the positions of the user name and password fields on the green screen send the User ID and password to those positions, and then send an Enter keystroke or whatever was needed to log on. You could then navigate to another screen e.g. a search screen, send the data and keystrokes to perform a search, then grab the resulting data from the green screen.   Another approach is to create Win/Web forms that replicate the green screen app and get data from the data stores directly. The advantage of this is that you don't have to know the keystrokes / navigation of the legacy application which could get cumbersome for a large green screen system. There's no right or wrong it depends on the circumstances. Our company did a mixture of both.

For your third question it depends on the type of reports you want. If they need to be real time then you can connect directly to the data store. If they don't need to be real time you could do nightly transfers of the data from the legacy system and store the data in SQL Server for example, then run your reports against the SQL Server data.

One answer for your 4th question is that you will definitely need to get your hands on someone that knows the green screen application. You will be spending hours and hours going through the screens on the legacy app so access to user(s) that know the system is crucial. Also you will need logon id and passwords etc.

Finally there are some 3rd party companies that specialise in transferring data from source to destination, one off the top of my head is Data Mirror. Another approach would be to use a middle tier integration product like BizTalk or Tibco, both of which take data from one or more sources and stick them in one or more destinations, but this may be overkill depending on your requirements.

Hope that helps and good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I use the Client Access (of whatever it's called now) drivers to connect to the server which I believe are based on ADO.NET. Through the version of the driver I have (we are on V5R4), you cannot and would have to create stored procedures to call the programs (which isn't hard). I thought I heard on the latest version you can execute programs, but I am not certain.

The only other thing I would look at is creating a user with only the authorities you need to do what you need to do in case someone gets a hold of that username and password, they cannot do too much. We had setup a read-only (`*USE`) user and a rwx (`*CHANGE`) user.

Answer (score 0):

[Sorry did not see that this is an old post. Hope its is still useful]

I have written both green screen and .Net applications. From my experience..

1.
ODBC - works but you need to set ODBC settings at all user PC. .NET Data Provider is better due to more .net specific stuffs inside and don't need to set ODBC settings at all clients. Before .net provider available in as400, i mostly use OLEDB.   Refer to http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/access/windows/dotnet/ for details

2.Use stored procedures. Stored procedures normally faster than putting all logics inside .net. Create either SQL or external stored procedure written in RPG,CL,COBOL,C++,etc... I don't re-write all RPG old logic in .net, i just change old RPG program little bit and make it into External stored procedure

3.For reports, again use stored procedures that passed back result sets. Its fast, cleaner and works well with Crystal Report.

4.Technical details. If you have many clients to install the program - use Web Services - you don't have to install Client Access with correct version at all PCs.

Watch your OS400 version.
If using OS400 version V6R1 and above, make sure client access used is V5R4 or higher - Stored procedures might not works well in older Client Access.

ODBC works in older client access but i think .NET Data Provider only works in V5R3.

If you compile .net program using .NET Data Provider V6R1, then you user client access also have to be V6R1.

Use Stored Procedure whenever possible for security (don't need to expose tables) and simplify program logic (can re-use RPG program)

On OS400 side, make sure system value QCCSID is set with proper CCSID e.g. 37 for English. ODBC,OLEDB, .net driver will automatically convert/translate proper character to your .Net program. Never leave the value as 65535.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do not change system value QCCSID from 65535 without significant testing first. Although it's a very good idea not to run the system under 65535 if networking is important, some systems have their applications set to depend on it.